# ListView adapter getView() getting wrong item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and I put in the following code to see the getView() process of my BaseAdapter.

```
@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.d("getView()","Fetching Row: " + position);
    ...
}
```

As I scroll down my list slowly, I notice something strange happening. Even when I'm at list position 40-50ish, it's still calling getView() with a position of 0-7. Here is what my log looks like:

```
05-14 11:46:13.989: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 45
05-14 11:46:14.039: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 0
05-14 11:46:14.049: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 1
05-14 11:46:14.049: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 2
05-14 11:46:14.049: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 3
05-14 11:46:14.059: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 4
05-14 11:46:14.059: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 5
05-14 11:46:14.059: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 6
05-14 11:46:14.069: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 7
05-14 11:46:14.320: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 46
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 0
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 1
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 2
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 3
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 4
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 5
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 6
05-14 11:46:14.430: I/getView()(18681): Fetching Row: 7
```

As you can see, in between row 45 and row 46, it called getView() for row 0-7, each time. This happens for every list item. I'm afraid this is causing performance issues.

Why is this happening? And is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your listview xml change the layout_height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: Wow, couldn't have thought it was that simple. Thanks for the solution!! Do you happen to know why setting android:layout_height="wrap_content" causes the listview to do that?

Comment: The layout is getting recalculate everytime because of the wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. The `ListView` has a number of internal optimizations to actually improve performance - one of which is to recycle views and only display rows that are actually on the screen. In other words, `ListView` does not work by rendering all x number of views in your adapter and then simply move them on and off the screen. Rather, it creates views as they are displayed. This is why when you're on item 45 in your list it still refers to those rows as item 0 through 7. The `ListView` is only displaying 7 or 8 views at a time - i.e. what fits on the screen - even though your adapter contains many more. This makes a big difference as your lists get longer since it saves the device from having to render every view in advance.

As a result to get one of the views is slightly more complicated than simply using `getView()` since there is a good chance, depending on the length of the list, that it may not exist.