# ListView row finding incorrect View

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have a listview of plots with a ListViewAdapter which has a method for addind data to an individual plot:

```
public void AddData(Sensor sensor, float[] data)
{
    double[] dat = Array.ConvertAll(data, x => (double)x);
    Plot plot;
    if (_PlotMap.TryGetValue(sensor, out plot))
    {
        plot.AddData(dat);
    }
}
```

This method uses the 'Sensor' argument to determine which plot the data is for. The Sensor maps to a plot via the _PlotMap. _PlotMap is generated as each row is added to the list like so:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    PlotView pvPlot;

    if (row == null) row = LayoutInflater.From(_Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MonitorPlotLineListViewRow, null, false);
    pvPlot = row.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.pvPlot);
    var linePlot = new LinePlot(_Context, pvPlot, _Sensors[position], _Application.XAxisWidthSeconds, _panning, false, _frameTime, 1000);
    if (!_PlotMap.ContainsKey(_Sensors[position]))
       _PlotMap.TryAdd(_Sensors[position], linePlot);

    return row;
}
```

My issue is here:

```
pvPlot = row.FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.pvPlot);
```

It randomly returns plotviews, not necessarily the plotview from the row that is being generated. Thanks in advance.

**edit:**
I've watched the ID's as the activity is created and this is the result (the GetView method is called a bunch of times during OnCreate):

1. Generates row 0 -> plot has ID 0, convertview 0
2. Generates row 1 -> plot has ID 1, convertview 1
3. Generates row 0 -> plot has ID 0, convertview 0
4. Generates row 1 -> plot has ID 0, convertview 0
5. Generates row 0 -> plot has ID 0, convertview 0
6. Generates row 1 -> plot has ID 0, convertview 0

Comment: So you have multiple views with the same id?

Comment: Yes, when I Go back and check the PlotViews of the plots that have been generated (there are 2 at the moment), they have the same reference.

Comment: shouldn't it be pvPlot = (PlotView) row.findViewById(R.id.pvPlot)? Whay do you have it different?

Comment: Sorry this is Xamarin code (Android for C#). Some of the syntax is different but it is functionally (mostly) identical.

Comment: Add the xamarin tag to the question

Comment: You do know what an ID is right? As in "identifier"? Why are you surprised the code cant tell the difference between multiple items with the same ID?

Comment: Given it's the generation of a row, and given that I'm calling: row.FindViewById, I would assume that it searches within the row for the view? I am surprised because it is finding the view from a different row object.

Comment: You are aware that ListView reuses views, by design? So convertView may be a view that has already been databound with a different collection item. Is that what's happening?

Comment: I am aware, though my understanding is not great. I know rows get recycled when they go off screen, but unless the same row is being shown twice at the same time (can this happen?) then each row should have it's own set of views correct?

Comment: I've edited to show the ID's as the activity is created.

Answer (score 0):

So for whatever reason, I needed to change the XML file. Originally the height of the ListView was 400dp, changing it to match_parent fixed this. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16551030/6936275